# Is there a maximum number of notifications Trello can notify a user of?

Tags: trello, notifications

I recently went on vacation for 10 days. I have several Trello boards associated with work, and several additional shared and unshared personal boards. I didn't check Trello the whole time I was gone, and when I logged in for the first time upon my return, I believe I had 15 notifications. (I also forgot to turn on email alerts - I've never used them before because Trello is open the whole time I'm at my computer.)

It's been a few days now, and I realized that I missed a whole lot of activity, including @alerts in comments, because I hadn't seen notifications. My notifications page actually lists **43 events/alerts** that occurred during my vacation.

Does that little red number of unread notifications have a max value? Do I have to actually click through the whole notification stream and manually check the time frame I was gone in order to see everything that happened while I was away?

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum number of notifications.

Currently, there is no easy way to clear all notifications, though that's something the team wants to fix. There is a card for it here: https://trello.com/c/NkUJU0jE